# get the field layout metadata from record page

Tags: apex, lightning-experience, metadata, xml

I wanna get fields from a record page.
So tried to use metadata query in apex, but it did not look working well.

Below is the code that I tried.
What should I write in the code to get fields metadata in apex?

```
try{
    List<Metadata.Metadata> components = Metadata.Operations.retrieve(
        Metadata.MetadataType.Layout,
        new List<String>{'Account-Account Layout'}
    );
    layout = (Metadata.Layout)components.get(0);
}catch(Exception e){
    System.debug(e.getMessage());
}
```

In the `e.getMessage`, the debug `List index out of bounds: 0` was shown.

Or should I use xml code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To cover the obvious, have you double-checked that that layout name exists? Is the layout you're trying to receive part of a managed package?

Comment: Yes, might be layout name issue. This code is working fine and getting layout information.

Comment: @DavidReed
Could you tell me how can I know the layout name? Should I add some additional code to get layout name? or is it possible to check layout name from Salesforce setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code appears to be correct, so I believe the problem is simply that your org does not contain a Page Layout called `"Account-Account Layout"`.

If you navigate to the Account sObject in Setup->Object Manager, and click Layouts, you'll see a list of layout names:

[image: Layout list]

The metadata component name for each layout is of the form `"<sObject API name>-<layout name>"`, where the layout name is what is shown here. Note however that if either the sObject or the layout is managed, namespaces will be present on the managed entity:

```
<sObject package namespace>__<sObject name>-<layout package namespace>__<layout name>
```

If in doubt, you can use a Tooling API query to get the `FullName` property:

```
SELECT FullName FROM Layout WHERE Id = '<an id>'
```

The Id is in the URL for each layout's detail page.

Comment: Thank you so much David!
I got the metadata from your answer!
If you permit, could you make advice also to this question?
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/268654/update-global-picklist-values-without-using-tooling-api
Thank you for your kindness.